# Calibrations settings stored in monitor

Tags: display, lcd, led

I recently bought new Samsung SyncMaster S22B300B. Its colors were awesome. To play with its settings comfortably using mouse, I installed [Samsung MagicTune](http://www.samsung.com/pk/consumer/learningresources/monitor/magetune/pop_intro.html). There are two calibration options in it. MagicWizard, and Color Calibrtaion. I ran them both and damn.

Now it looks even uglier then those cheap hp LCD monitors in my computer lab. Either it is too bright that I can not see the white boxes (grey levels) from 244-254 [White saturation - Lagom LCD test](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/white.php) or too dark to distinguish 1-15 [Black level - Lagom LCD test](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/black.php) when I calibrate colors/gamma using MagicTune

Either this
[image]
or this
[image]

I thought these calibration settings are stored in windows, I attached this monitor to the laptop and it gives the same result. Resetting monitor settings do nothing once I calibrate using magic tune. Not even when I attach it to the laptop Looks like those settings are stored in monitor.

Has anyone encountered the same issue with MagicTune? As this calibration seems permanent, Is there anyway to hard reset?

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a daft question, but did you read section 5 of [the manual](http://mypdfmanuals.com/dref/4313200)? It actually suggests what to do if image is too light and could have something to do with the way the viewing angle is set up as well as other options which could help your situation?

Comment: I have seen the manual. I have tried all contrast brightness and magic angel settings. Nothing effects other than that MagicTune color calibration. But it is still not enough, nothing like before. As clouds have very light shade of gray, they look plain white at many points.

Comment: What a shame monitors do not come with a factory reset button. I would try and call Samsung and see what they say, but as per their manual it looks like they believe it can be solved with the provided software! If this is the case I'm sure they'll be able to instruct you (or at least tell you where the magical restore to default settings button is!)

Comment: There is reset option, but it does not effect this problem. :( There should be a kind of Hard Reset function somewhere.